# Detect exception context in .NET Standard 2.1

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard

I'm migrating some .NET 5 code to .NET Standard 2.1 for broader consumption but the `Marshal.GetExceptionPointers()` method isn't standardized.

Is there an alternative way to detect an exception context in .NET Standard 2.1?

**Current Code**

```cs
  public static bool IsInExceptionContext()
            => Marshal.GetExceptionPointers() != IntPtr.Zero || Marshal.GetExceptionCode() != 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use the reflection:

```cs
public static class ExceptionHelper
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo GetExceptionPointersMethod = typeof(Marshal).GetMethod("GetExceptionPointers");

    public static bool IsInExceptionContext()
    {
        var ptr = (IntPtr)GetExceptionPointersMethod.Invoke(null, null);

        if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid reflection (for performance reasons), you can build dynamically a `LambdaExpression`  that will call the `Marshal.GetExceptionPointers()` method.

```cs
internal static class ExceptionHelper
{
    private static readonly Func<IntPtr> GetExceptionPointers = BuildGetExceptionPointersFunc();

    public static bool IsInExceptionContext()
    {
        var ptr = GetExceptionPointers();

        if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static Func<IntPtr> BuildGetExceptionPointersFunc()
    {
        var memberAccess = Expression.Call(typeof(Marshal).GetMethod("GetExceptionPointers"));

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IntPtr>>(memberAccess);

        return lambda.Compile();
    }
}
```